# how to unmap some key bindings for a particular site in vimperator

Tags: firefox-addon, vimperator

I am using vimperator for firefox and it works well on most websites. However for [webogram](http://web.telegram.org) there is a conflict on the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key when focusing on the message box. When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it seems vimperator intercept the event and add a newline character, while originally it should be the trigger to send the message inputed.

I tried temporarily disable vimperator with the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key, then everything works well. However, I want to have other features like hints of vimperator enabled normally. So the best way to solve the conflict seems to be disabling the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key binding for this website.

I expect something like:

```
scoped_iunmap web.telegram.org <CR>
```

Is there a way I can achieve the effect like that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a temporary solution for this requirement.

```
ignorekeys add web\\.telegram\\.org -except o,t,T,O,<C-l>,f,F,:
```

The frequently used bindings are preserved, add in the `-except` list as you wish.

This is not very elegant and I'm still looking for a better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the [feed some keys vimperator plugin](https://github.com/vimpr/vimperator-plugins). It sounds like it's the perfect match for what you want. Unfortunately the docs for it might be a little out of date. Here's how I use it on github.com, duckduckgo.com, and feedly.com:

```
command! -nargs=+ lazy autocmd VimperatorEnter .* <args>
lazy fmaps -u='github\.com/[^/]+/.+' -events=vkeydown s,t gc gi gp gw
lazy fmaps -u='duckduckgo\.com/\?q=' -events=vkeydown l j k <enter> s,d gm,m gt,t
lazy fmaps -u='feedly\.com' j k v A m s
```

Basic installation:

1. Install the `feedSomeKeys_3.js` file in `~/.vimperator/plugin`.
2. Install the `_libly.js` file in `~/.vimperator/plugin`.
3. Add your fmaps to your ~/.vimperatorrc file.
4. Restart your browser.
5. Dance! (Technically this is optional.)